when making changes in Sanity Studio my local dev app is not being update
I'm currently working on a website using Next.js and Sanity. But I've noticed that when I update a product in the Sanity Studio, my local development page is not showing the changes. Is there a way to make that as soon as I publish new updates in Sanity, they're instantly updating on my local development page as well?
This is my code:
import ShopNav from "@/app/components/ShopNav/ShopNav";
import { client } from "../../lib/sanity";
import { simplifiedProduct } from "@/app/interface";
import Image from "next/image";

async function getData() {
  const query = `*[_type == "product"]| order(_createdAt desc) {
    _id,
    price,
    "imageUrl": images[0].asset->url,
    name,
      "slug":slug.current,
      "categoryName": category->name  
  }`;

  const data = await client.fetch(query);

  return data;
}

export default async function Page() {
  const data: simplifiedProduct[] = await getData();

  return (
    <section className="md:h-full flex items-center text-gray-600"........

I tried adding { cache: "no-store" } to the query or export const dynamic = "force-dynamic" at the end of my page but it only worked once and after making changes  again they are not being updated. And I tried adding { next : { revalidate : 3600 }}); to query as well and waited 1 hour but still nothing changed.

Try hard reloading your browser
